# Regex for 2 words, non-numeric, and one space

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to build a javascript regex that allows users to enter 2 words only, non-numeric, and only one space between them. I have been trying this one: ^\w+\s*\w+ ?$ but don't know how to avoid numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 2 words only use the alphabets without any special characters.

You can use the simplest one. `/^([a-z]+)\s+([a-z]+)(\s*)$/gi`

```
 [a-z]+ tells any character in the alphabet with quantifier of one or more
 \s* -> is a space with a quantifier of zero or more
  i -> on the last part tells case-insensitive matching
```

```js
let a = 'my Word';
let b = 'oneWord';
let c = 'using three words';
let d = 'onewordwithspace ';
let e = 'my wordwithSpace ';

let regEx = /^([a-z]+)\s+([a-z]+)(\s*)$/gi;

console.log((regEx.test(a))); // true
console.log((regEx.test(b))); // false
console.log((regEx.test(c))); // false
console.log((regEx.test(d))); // false
console.log((regEx.test(e))); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
([A-Za-z]+)\s([A-Za-z]+)$
```

Comment: This also works too, but it does not work with one word. Sorry, I did not mention this in my question. Thank you anyway :)